Shorten multiple patterns that has a prefix
I use the following sed command to delete all lines except that match containing patterns:
sed '/orders="Green\|orders="Orange\|orders="Blue/!d'

This works, but how do you make it shorter so that orders=" is only used one time?
sed '/orders="["Green","Orange","Blue"]/!d'

Something like this matches any of the characters between brackets,
but ignores the whole word.

What is the source file? Code? Which language?

sed '/orders="\(Green\|Orange\|Blue\)/d'

sed line selection uses regular expression, and by default, without the -E/-r option, the Basic flavor is used.
What you want to use is Groups - \(regexp\)
So something like this:
sed '/orders="\(Green\|Orange\|Blue\)/!d'


@nawny sed 'a\|b' is GNU sed specific; for eg. with echo a | sed 's/a\|b/c/' I get a on macOS; IMHO it's better to use the -E switch that simplifies the syntax and shows exactly what standard you're using: sed -E '/orders="(Green|Orange|Blue)/!d'

@Fravadona, it does look more readable. Thanks for the suggestion.


This works, but how do you make it shorter so that orders=" is only used one time?

Perform the alternation inside a group.  You have the right idea, but the wrong regex syntax.  This is what you want:
sed '/orders=("Green"\|"Orange"\|"Blue")/!d'

But inasmuch as that pattern suggests that you may be trying to match XML, I feel obligated to advise you that you should use a bona fide XML parser, perhaps one incorporated into an XSLT processor, if that's really wht you're doing.

Whis did you repeat double quotes?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub, because in conjunction with "You have the right idea, but the wrong regex syntax", I wrote the pattern as a variation on the OP's attempt.  The quotes don't need to be duplicated, but evidently, it seemed good to the OP to do so. And I think I actually find the result a little easier to read myself, at a cost of only four extra characters.  If they want to squeeze out the extra quotes, too, then I leave that as an exercise for them.

@JohnBollinger, you're right it's XML. It doesn't seem to work though.
